# Finding Key-Value Coding Paths

Tags: ios, interface-builder, key-value-coding

Key-value coding paths are useful in UIKit. They often allow you to configure elements that aren't specified in the public API of a view, or in the Interface Builder inspector for that view.

For instance, you can configure the text color of `UIDatePicker` using `textColor` key path, but there doesn't seem to be a property or method exposing that configuration -- the only way to do it is through key-value coding.

Given that -- how can one as an iOS developer find key-value coding paths for elements? I found this particular example in a StackOverflow response, but how did they find it? I'd love to be able to inspect these classes and find their key-value coding paths myself, or at least have a good crowdsourced reference to all the KVC key paths that might be useful when I'm trying to customize a view.

Comment: Keep in mind that using such undocumented key paths can cause code to break or crash if things change in an update to iOS. There's also the chance an app could be rejected. It's never safe to use undocumented features.

Comment: So if you're going to use the User-Defined Runtime Attributes in Interface Builder, you'd recommend you only use it to define attributes that are exposed as public properties in the API, then?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [class-dump](http://stevenygard.com/projects/class-dump/) to view all properties on an Objective-C class, including private properties (properties with the `_` underscore prefix)

But also yes as @rmaddy said, most of the time you won't want to modify private properties-- but it should be pretty safe if you are just reading and not writing.  For example, `NSUndoManager` has a private property, `_undoStack`, which is super useful to read so you can see what is currently in your undo stack